# Get last value from Observable

Tags: rx-swift

How can `combineLatest` be used to return a `BehaviorSubject`? I'm trying to get the last value out of the observable.

```
var things: Observable<Thing>

// driven by UI
var selectedThingIndex: PublishSubject<Int>

// this is a BehaviorSubject, because I need to get the latest value outside a subscriber
var currentThing: BehaviorSubject<Thing> = BehaviorSubject.combineLatest(things, selectedThingIndex) { things, index in
    things[index]
}

// Get the last value
let thing = currentThing.value()
```

I can't get this to compile, because `combineLatest` returns an `Observable`, which doesn't seem to be castable to a `BehaviorSubject`. I tried an explicit cast, e.g. `as? BehaviorSubject<Thing?>` but that returns nil.

Comment: Note... `Observable`s and `Subject`s should be `let`s not `var`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create the BehaviorSubject and then bind your combined observable to it:

```
let currentThing = BehaviorSubject<Thing?>(value: nil)
Observable.combineLatest(things, selectedThingIndex) { $0[$1] }
    .bind(to: currentThing)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```